# DateTime Issue in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I toke as example this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartTime.java
I adjusted to my needs. The problem is that for plotting data in X axis it need a float number and converting from long to float there is lost of datas. The trick in the example is to convert milliseconds time in HOURLY so there isn't lost of data but i need to convert to DAILY, I tried but couldn't get the results

I've tried to change `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis((long) value);` to `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis((long) value);` and I added `timeInHours = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(mDate.getTime());`

```
public class ChartDailyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LineChart chart;
    DBOpenHelper mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart_daily);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setChart();

    }


    public void setChart(){

        chart = findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);
        xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        //xAxis.setSpaceMin(1000f*60f*60f*24f);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

            private final SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy", Locale.ITALIAN);

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                long millis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis((long) value);

                return mFormat.format(new Date(millis));

            }

        });

        mDB = new DBOpenHelper(this);

        YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
        leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMaximum((float) mDB.queryMaxTotaleBevuto());
        leftAxis.setYOffset(-9f);
        leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));

        YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

        setData();

    }

    private void setData() {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList xList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList yList = new ArrayList<String>();

        DBOpenHelper mDB = new DBOpenHelper(this);

        xList = mDB.queryTotaleBevutoData();
        yList = mDB.queryTotaleBevuto();

        float flX, flY;
        int intX, intY;

        for(int x=0; x<xList.size(); x++){

            String givenDateString = (String)xList.get(x);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

            long timeInHours = 0;

            try {

                Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                //Log.d("XLOGGIN:", "Date = " + givenDateString );
                timeInHours = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(mDate.getTime());
                //timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            intX = (int)timeInHours;
            intY = (int)yList.get(x);

            flX = (float)intX;
            flY = (float)intY;
/*
            Log.d("XLOGGIN:Long", Long.toString(timeInMilliseconds));
            Log.d("XLOGGIN:intX", Integer.toString(intX));
            Log.d("XLOGGIN:flX", Float.toString(flX));
*/
            values.add(new Entry(flX, flY));

        }

        // create a dataset and give it a type
        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Drinked ml/Day");
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set1.setValueTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
        set1.setDrawCircles(false);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
        set1.setFillAlpha(65);
        set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);

        // create a data object with the data sets
        LineData data = new LineData(set1);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);

        // set data
        chart.setData(data);
    }

}
```

The chart plots bad datetime (all dates are 01/01/1970) and the line is a orizzontal line

Comment: Thanks for your time.If I uncomment the code, timeInMilliseconds is correct

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting your timestamp into a day equivalent. This is how you should do it (during setData()):

```
        try {

            Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
            //Log.d("XLOGGIN:", "Date = " + givenDateString );
            timeInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(mDate.getTime());
            //timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```